# How does one fix the position of a text-box or drawn shape on an MS-Excel-2010 graph (under WIN7)?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

Having positioned an arrow shape and a small text box onto an MS-Excel-2010 graph, when I re-position the graph, the shape and text-box don't move with the graph.

Can anyone please advise me how to fix them to the graph?

I've searched both Excel Help and Superuser - to no avail.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you placed them on top of the graph.  I have 2016 and I can't remember if these looked the same in 2010, but this is the way that I get to these options in 2016, but you have to have the chart selected before you insert the text box.

[image: Excel Insert Command Bar]

If you see all these options available, then you don't have the chart selected, as then it will give you only limited options as shown here.  For example, PivotChart in the Charts section should be grayed out if you have a chart selected.

Bottom line:  If you put just a regular text box on top of a chart, it will not move with it.  Excel doesn't even give you the option to Group it with another shape.  However, when you do it as I've described, it will move with and, to a limited degree, adjust to size changes of the chart.

Comment: Yes - that's done it. I had earlier graphs on which the text and shapes remained in place, but didn't realise I must have had the graph selected on those occasions. Many thanks, Rey

Comment: Just to complement the answer: this technique works when resizing/moving the "chart area" (i.e. the area which include the title, the legend, etc). If you move the "plot area" (i.e. only the graph in itself), then the text does not move along.